# Providing compiler flags to Rust build for the MSVC toolchain

Tags: visual-c++, rust, rust-cargo

I am looking to enable compiler options for Rust applications built on Windows using the MSVC toolchain. I see that rustc provides the option "-C llvm-args" to provide flags to the LLVM toolchain but I don't see such an option for MSVC. Does this support currently exist for rustc or cargo?

Comment: Note that rustc never uses the MSVC _compiler_ but only the MSVC _linker._ You can pass options to the linker with [`-C link-arg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#link-arg) or [`-C link-args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#link-args).

Comment: @Jmb What compiler does rustc use on Windows?

Comment: rustc _is_ the compiler so it doesn't use any other compiler. However it relies on the LLVM backend for actual code generation on all platforms. So if you need to pass arguments to the backend, you can use `-C llvm-args` on Windows like in other platforms.

Comment: @Jmb thanks, that answers my question. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rustc is the Rust compiler and it relies on the LLVM backends for actual code generation on all platforms. So if you need to pass arguments to the backend, you can use `-C llvm-args` on Windows like in other platforms.

The distinction between the MSVC toolchain or the MINGW toolchain mostly concerns the linker. Options can be passed to the linker with [`-C link-arg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#link-arg) or [`-C link-args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/codegen-options/index.html#link-args) on all platforms, although of course in this case the available options will depend on the targeted toolchain.